# Difference between Taylor's theorem and Taylor's series?

Tags: calculus

What does Taylor's theorem say? How do we use Taylor's theorem to get to Taylor's series? I need the basic idea behind these two. What's going on between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rougly, the Taylor theorem says: if $f$ has enough derivatives in a nhood of the point $a$, then $f$ is the sum of a polynomial and a *remainder*:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x - a)^k + R_k(x).$$
**If** you can calculate the derivatives (see [What do Taylor series accomplish?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661444/what-do-taylor-series-accomplish/2661619#2661619)) and the remainder is "small",
$$f(x) \approx\hbox{ a polynomial.}$$
Why this is important? Because polynomials are *calculable*.

If $f$ is $C^\infty$, you can write the Taylor series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x - a)^k,
$$
**but**
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x - a)^k
$$
can be **false**. When is true (this depends obviously of the behavior of the remainder) we say that the function is *analytic*. But being $C^\infty$ **isn't** enough. The function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ne 0$, $f(0) = 0$ is $C^\infty$ but its Taylor series at $x = 0$ is **zero**. Even worse: there are examples of functions with *divergent* Taylor series (*Real Mathematical Analysis* by C. Pugh).

Comment: I like the contrast you make between the Taylor approximation by a Taylor polynomial and the series actually converging to the function. This remainder going to 0 condition is often neglected; it should be mention even if it is not needed to state Taylor's theorem. I think it would be really helpful to mention them together within the same theorem (at least I know that baby Rudin doesn't do so).

Comment: @Martin-Blas Why we want that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$? I think it is enough to say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Please reply I am confused at this point.

Comment: @MANI, differentiability in a neighborhood of $a$ isn't strictly *necessary*, but it is *useful*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Although the exact syntax of Taylor theorem is not agreed upon generally the basic of the theorem is:

For every $k\in\Bbb N$ differentiable function at some point $a$, $f$, exists $h_k$ such that $$\lim_{x\to a}h_k(x)=0,\;f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+h_k(x)(x-a)^k$$

Taylor series is:

> - if $f$ is of class $C^\omega$, then $h_k(x)=\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n-k-1}$

The difference is that not all functions are class $C^\omega$

---

Few more things things that the theorem says is that if there exists polynomial, $p(x)$, such that $f(x)=p(x)+h_k(x)(x-a)^k$, then $p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$(uniqueness)

If so we can calculate the approximation error: $R_k(x)=f(x)-p(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}R_k(x)=o(|x-a|^k)$.

Using this we can get $|R_k(x)|\le M\frac{|x-a|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$