# Why are Taylor series useful?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I think I have a good grasp on the fundamentals of Taylor series (what they do and how they approximate the functions), but I just don't understand how these can be useful.

For example, lets look at the following Taylor series:

$$e^x\approx 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^4}{4!}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}\dotsb.$$

Why would you want to use the approximation when you have the actual equation $e^x$. It not only look simpler, but also gives you the true value of this function for any value of $x$; so why use Taylor series for which gives you just an approximation.

Maybe the point I am missing is that Taylor Series can give you an approximation on unknown functions, i.e. $f(x) = ???$.

But then you wouldn't be able to find derivatives of this function?

Could someone please help me see **Taylor Series** as an actual tool that can be used to solve real life problems (with an example ideally)?

Comment: Related: [What are power series used for? (a reference request)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766798/13130) *AND* [Physical applications of higher terms of Taylor series](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2152/745)

Comment: Just to check: In your way of thinking, is their any importance to the numerical value of $e^{-2}$ computed accurate to 10 decimal places? I can think of a probabilist wanting to know these kinds of things, but if I'm going to bother writing this as an answer, I need to know what you regard as important.

Comment: Not worth making another answer for, but in addition to the points below about extending a function from the reals to the complex numbers, it also allows us to do some really fun and crazy (yet still useful things) such as define $e^A$ where $A$ is a matrix. This aids in solving systems of differential equations. One could even attempt to define a derivative operator this way ie $$e^{\frac{d}{dx}}$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using a calculator, a set of tables, etc, how would find the value of $e^x$?  For some people, that series actually is the definition of $e^x$.

A more general use is expanding the domain of a function e,g. from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Another is integration of a function for which there is no anti-derivative.

Answer (score 3):

One simple example is the Simple pendulum, with length $l$ and in gravitational acceleration $g$. The differential equation we need to solve is:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \varphi}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\frac{g}{l} \sin(\varphi)=0$$
Which, sadly, can't be solved analytically with the "common" functions. But if we use the first order Taylor polinomial of the $\sin$ function, i.e. $\sin(\varphi)\approx \varphi$, we get the following equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \varphi}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+\frac{g}{l}\varphi=0$$
Which can be solved easily:
$$\varphi=\varphi_0 \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}t\right)$$
Which is valid if the angle (and the ellapsed time) is small enough.

Answer (score 2):

Taylor Series might be helpful in identifying the asymptotic behavior of functions. Once we decompose a function into its Taylor Series, we sometimes see terms that are vanishing in the limit and can simplify the expression if we are only interested in its limiting behavior.

A good example of such a decomposition is the proof of [Stirling's formula](http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/hanoiex/counting/Stirling.pdf), where thanks to Taylor Series expansion, we identify a geometric series to complete the proof.

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications :

Computing limits

Study of continuity

Study of differentiability

Study of the sign

Finding tangent equation

Finding asymptote equation

Nature of a series

Nature of an improper integral

Nature of a singular point

Resolution of differential equations

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are about the easiest things to deal with.  They're easy to integrate and easy to differentiate.  When we have non-polynomial functions, that might not be the case.  Can you integrate $e^x/x$?  No.  But you can approximate it by  a Taylor polynomial at any accuracy you like, and then easily integrate.

If you have a complicated limit, you can often replace the stubborn bits with their Taylor series and then easily find the limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Taylor's theorem as an infinite series to "estimate" functions, then you're abusing it. The *correct* form of Taylor's Theorem, for such usages, doesn't give you estimates, but *exact* values and formulae - that's Taylor's Theorem with remainder. In other words, you use it for curve-sculpting and for solving functional equations.

That includes interpolation, as a special case, by the way. More generally it includes *smooth* interpolation, where you have conditions not just on function at a set of points but on their derivatives.

It also includes - as a special case - the order $1$(!) Taylor's Theorem - which is purely algebraic, not even involving derivatives at all (except as a condition)

> If $f(x)$ is absolutely differentiable between $a$ and $x$, then $f(x) - f(a)$ factors into $(x - a)g(x,a)$ for some continuous function $g(x,a)$ of $x$ and $a$.

Here's an example of curve sculpting:

> Find the "most general" function $f(x)$, such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, $f'(0) = 0 = f'(1)$.

By "most general", we mean one which has suitable conditions on its derivatives. Here, that means it has absolutely continuous derivatives up to and including order $4$.

Use the order $2$ Taylor's Theorem with $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$:
$$f(x) = f(0) + x f'(0) + x^2 g(x) = x^2 g(x),$$
for some function $g(x)$. Differentiating, we have $f'(x) = 2x g(x) + x^2 g'(x)$, therefore:
$$1 = f(1) = 1^2 g(1) = g(1), \quad 0 = f'(1) = 2 g(1) + 1^2 g'(1) = 2 + g'(1)\quad⇒\quad g'(1) = -2.$$

By assumption $g(x)$ is has absolutely continuous derivatives up to the second order. So, we can use order 2 Taylor's Theorem on $g(x)$ at $x = 1$:
$$g(x) = g(1) + (x - 1)g'(1) + (x - 1)^2 h(x) = 1 - 2(x - 1) + (x - 1)^2 h(x),$$
for some continuous function $h(x)$. Thus, the general solution to the original problem is:
$$f(x) = x^2(3 - 2x) + (x(x - 1))^2 h(x),$$
for some continuous function $h(x)$.

Further conditions may then be used to determine $h(x)$, based on the context where the problem occurs in. The function $f(x)$, for instance, can be used to smoothly drive a motion or transition from point $x = 0$ to $x = 1$.

**Example:**
Transition functions were determined, by conditions like this, and used at several place in this video

**Invasion From Planet Chicago**: Independence Day II
https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/156311459

Now, interpolation.

> Find the "most general" function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 4$.

... again, with the usual qualifier on "most general".

First, by the order 1 Taylor's Theorem at $x = 0$, we have
$$f(x) = x g(x),$$
for some function $g(x)$. Then
$$1 = f(1) = g(1), \quad 4 = f(2) = 2 g(2)\quad⇒\quad g(2) = 2.$$
Second, use the order 1 Taylor's Theorem at $x = 1$, to get:
$$g(x) = 1 + (x - 1)h(x),$$
for some function $h(x)$. Then
$$2 = g(2) = 1 + h(2)\quad⇒\quad h(2) = 1.$$
Finally, use the order 1 Taylor's Theorem at $x = 2$, to get:
$$h(x) = 1 + (x - 2)k(x),$$
for some function $k(x)$. Then, upon substitution, we find that the most general solution for $f(x)$ is:
$$f(x) = x^2 + x(x - 1)(x - 2)k(x).$$
This is not an approximate result - but *exact*. The function $k(x)$ can be narrowed down upon by other conditions derived from the context of the problem.